# not able to do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string as following:

```
"{
    "TotalAmount":{"XPos":"100","YPos":"750"},
    "title":{"XPos":"250","YPos":"800"},
    "ListSetting":{
        "listId":"batchlist",
        "listXPos":"30",
        "listYPos":"700",
        "listCols":"["seq","RemitType"]"
    }
}"
```

I want to parse this string into a Dictionary of keys as TotalAmount, title and ListSetting, but when doing DeserializeObject as following, error occurs.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonStr);

An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code    
Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path 'ListSetting.listCols', line 1, position 166.
```

Looks like "listCols" is causing problem, but I don't know how to fix it. 
Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried Dictionary<string, string>, but it will fail at {"XPos":"100","YPos":"750"}. XPos, listYPos  etc are consistent.

Comment: Could you please show c# classes which you serialized?

Comment: @Yauhen Sampir 
Thank you, I tried changing the way to serialize and looks like all is goos now

Comment: Also you can validate your json in https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e726383419474d09aec762ce0de66a93 or other services like this

Comment: @Yauhen Sampir 
Got it! Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes `"` around your `listcols` array like `"listCols":["seq","RemitType"]` otherwise it's not treated as array object at all and obviously deserialization would fail

Comment: Thanks! I tried another method to serialize the JSON (so the quotes would be removed) and looks like it works. Thank you.